# openstack-cinder, how to resize a volume?

Tags: openstack, cinder

http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-blockstorage-v2.html

i can't find volume extend API...
how to extend openstack volume size??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows zero effort!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by source code it would be something like:

POST //volumes//action

And post content:

{ os-extend : { new_size:  } }